# Incorrect date format while exporting to csv

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am newbie to c# and I am trying to export table data from sqlite 3 database to csv but datetime format has changed in csv the format in sqlite 3 is:

```
2013-04-16 21:33:42.000
```

while datetime in csv is showing up like:

```
16/04/2013 21:33:42,
```

This is my code:

```
SQLiteConnection m_dbConnection;
//m_dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source= C:/Users/IT-Administrator/Desktop/WebMobility.db; Version=3;");

m_dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data source = F:/Explor/final test/WebMobility.db; Version=3;");
m_dbConnection.Open();

SQLiteCommand myCommand = new SQLiteCommand();
myCommand.Connection = m_dbConnection;


myCommand.CommandText = "select CompanyId,`DateTime`,Serial,ShortDeviceId,MatricolaA,Upper(Targa),CommonRoadDescription,RoadCivicNumber,GpsAddress,VerbaliVehicleTypeDescription,VehicleBrandDescription,VehicleModelDescription,CommonColorVehicleDescription,VerbaliRuleOneCode,VerbaliRuleOneDescription,VerbaliClosedNoteDescription,VerbaliRuleOnePoints,VerbaliMissedNotificationDescription  from  VerbaliData";
//myCommand.Connection = myConn;
DataTable data = new DataTable();
SQLiteDataAdapter myAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(myCommand);
//myAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand;
myAdapter.Fill(data);
dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
this.dataGridView1.Refresh();
if (dataGridView1.RowCount > 0)
{
    string value = "";
    DataGridViewRow dr = new DataGridViewRow();
    StreamWriter swOut = new StreamWriter("F:/Explor/final test/finaltest12.csv");

    //write header rows to csv
    for (int i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        if (i > 0)
        {
            swOut.Write(",");
        }
        swOut.Write(dataGridView1.Columns[i].HeaderText);
    }

    swOut.WriteLine();

    //write DataGridView rows to csv
    for (int j = 0; j <= dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; j++)
    {
        if (j > 0)
        {
            swOut.WriteLine();
        }

        dr = dataGridView1.Rows[j];

        for (int i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            if (i > 0)
            {
                swOut.Write(",");
            }

            value = dr.Cells[i].Value.ToString();
            //replace comma's with spaces
            value = value.Replace(',', ' ');
            //replace embedded newlines with spaces
            value = value.Replace(Environment.NewLine, " ");

            swOut.Write(value);
        }
    }
    swOut.Close();
}

m_dbConnection.Close();
```

Comment: On which line exactly?

Comment: myCommand.CommandText = "select CompanyId,`DateTime`

Answer (score 2):

DateTime columns have no formats. It is just the tool used to show the column content that formats the column value in a particular format.
Said that it is obvious that you need to do the same thing to print your value on the CSV file.

Inside your internal loop, check if the column is the datetime one and then format its value to your likes.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
{
    if (i > 0)
    {
         swOut.Write(",");
    }
    // Datetime column content transformed  in a formatted string....
    if(i == 1)
       value = Convert.ToDateTime(dr.Cells[i].Value).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.fff");
    else
       ....
```

EDIT in case you have null or empty values in your cell then you need to check for that before trying to convert

```
    // Datetime column content transformed in a formatted string....
    if(i == 1)
    {
       object cellValue = dr.Cells[i].Value;
       value = (cellValue == DBNull.Value ? 
             string.Empty : Convert.ToDateTime(cellValue).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.fff");
    }
```

This will write an empty column where the date is expected. This could be correct or not, depending on how the CSV file is required. Instead of an empty string you could save a predefined value.

Comment: I think ToString("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss") can only be cast on DateTime vars, I might be wrong...

Comment: thanks steve for the reply  ....No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments .. i get this this error when i use your code.

Comment: With the updated code? Convert.ToDateTime is required to take an object value (the gridview row cell) and apply the ToString with the format required for a datatime value

Comment: Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types

Comment: That's another problem then, you have a cell empty or null and of course cannot be converted to any kind of string. In this case a different approach is required.

Comment: can you please let me know how can i solve this issue

Comment: Steve it works but it is in the same format.. what i used to get before.

Comment: 2013-04-16 21:33:42.000

Comment: but i get 20/02/2012 16:42:10

Comment: Can you confirm that your database table for the datetime column you really have a datetime set as datatype for that column. If yes then there is no reason to have a different formatted output on your csv file from the one requested with the pattern yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.fff

Answer (score 0):

```
if (i==1)
   {
    value = dr.Cells[i].Value.ToString();
    if (value!null)
    {
    string dt=DateTime.Parse(value).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss");
    swOut.Write(dt);
    }
    ......
    }
```

Comment: value = dr.Cells[i].DateTime.Parse(value).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss"); this gives me error

Comment: Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types error